# Content not displaying on page

Tags: pages

```
<?php

/* Template Name : Home
*/
?>
get_header(); ?>

 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

When I type anything on content editor of the page it doesn't show any thing.

How do I make it working?

Comment: *How do I make it working?*. By adding a loop ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the loop before and after and add the function the_content()

something like this:

```
<?php
/**
** Template Name : Home
**/
get_header(); ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding a loop you can query all your posts,  which you entered in the back end . just do it like this

```
    <?php 
    /**
     *    Template Name: Home 
     **/
     get_header();  

     //Here i added a loop to explain you.
      if ( have_posts() ) {
           while ( have_posts() ) {

           the_title();    // Post title

            the_content();  // Post Content here

         } // end while
     } // end if

 get_footer();   ?>
```

From the above  code I added a loop and within the loop two functions. which will get you the posts and its content, 
  `the_content` function will get you editor content.

Comment: Your post was flagged as very low quality. Please file an [edit] and add proper explanation to what your code does, how it works, etc. Dumping code is considered as low/bad quality answers. I'm not going to cast a vote to delete this right now, but please, rectify your problems

Comment: I added some explanations now. is it enough for the answer?